# ubuntu installation - boot

Tags: boot

this is my first time installing ubuntu on a pc, uninstalling windows 10 completely.

I followed the guide step by step and installed ubuntu correctly, but upon rebooting it keeps restarting staying in a loop; and from the boot manager (pressing F12) ubuntu does not appear.

I tried inserting the usb stick, and trying to reinstall it tells me that a version of ubuntu is already present.

So I tried from the cmd "efibootmgr - v" and I see that it is present; so I tried forcing the next boot a with "efibootmgr -n ", and on reboot the correct version of ubuntu starts (keeping all the changes I had made previously)

Despite changing the order with "efibootmgr -o", if I turn off the pc and turn it back on, my version of ubuntu does not appear.
To find it again I always have to start from the usb stick and force the next boot as above.
I would like the only version present to be the installed version of ubuntu and start automatically at boot time.

Does anyone have any way to help me solve it ?
p.s try to be very detailed because I don't have much experience about it.

thank you very much in advance

Comment: What brand/model system? Some only want to boot an entry with description as "Windows Boot Manager" We can create one that has that description but boots Ubuntu. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Hi, the brand is Acer /travelMate P and the bootInfo summary report is this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RmJw63yTVY/. Thanks for the help

Comment: Many Acer require "trust" setting in UEFI. Acer Travelmate B117 (success - after some UEFI boot troubles) Trust related
https://forum.siduction.org/index.php?topic=6272.0 Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: In both links it talks about entering the BIOS (pressing F2), but unfortunately it asks me for a password and the one I remember is wrong, is there any way around it ?

Comment: If you set an UEFI password, you must never forget it. You may be able to totally reset system by jumpering pins on motherboard or removing coin battery. But then you have to got back into UEFI and redo all the settings you changed, as it will revert to defaults. Best to review your system manual to see details.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably a problem with GRUB which hasn't been installed.

Once you've booted from the USB key, use these commands (check that /dev/sda is your hard drive where you've installed Ubuntu) :

```
sudo os-prober
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: If Grub hasn't been installed it wouldn't have booted like it did. The key for this issue is actually in the comment under the question.